# Add action to UIButton which in a customview

Tags: objective-c, view, uibutton, action, programmatically-created

I have a custom view and it has a UIButton. I add this view to my navigationItem's rightbarButtonItem, it's ok, but I have to add an action to this button.

Here is my code;

```
-(void)showMessage:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"next" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UpDownButtonView *buttonView = [[UpDownButtonView alloc] initWithNibName:@"UpDownButtonView" bundle:nil];
    [buttonView.upButton addTarget:self action:@selector(next:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonView.downButton addTarget:self action:@selector(prev:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buttonView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,95,34);
    UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView.view]; 

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
    [self setTitle:@"Details"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom view with a UIButton, what you need is alloc and init a UIBarButtonItem and put it on your nav bar

the code would look like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", @"Back Button") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: Yes but I may add more buttons or something so I need to do it in custom view. Any thoughts?